# Why doesn't `loadFont` close input stream? Should I close it?

Tags: java, javafx, inputstream

Looking at the documentation of [`Font#loadFont`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/Font.html#loadFont-java.io.InputStream-double-) I came across this remark:

> This method does not close the input stream.

Unfortunately, this is not explained or expanded upon. So my question is:

1. What are possible reasons the API won't close the input stream? Is it likely you would like to re-use the stream? 
   I mostly use this method like this:

   ```
   Font.loadFont(getClass().getResourceAsStream("path/to/font"), 13.0);
   ```

   to make sure the font is available for my application, so I never re-use the input stream, and I can't really think of a reason I'd want to.
2. Should I close the input stream myself? Should I expect any problems if I'm not closing the input stream? 
   In the past I've had problems with a font loaded this way, where some labels configured with this font started showing squares, while others (on the same scene!) kept working fine. Could this be related to not closing the input stream?

Comment: It is a good rule of thumb that you shouldn't close a stream you didn't open. In this case, the method doesn't open it, so it doesn't close it either. For instance, there is no reason you couldn't pass in the standard input stream: if the method closed the parameter stream, you would be stuffed if you needed it to be open to do something else after.

Comment: And no, you shouldn't close it yourself: use try with resources.

Comment: @AndyTurner - using try-with-resources is equivalent to closing it myself, just a syntactic sugar. What I meant is should I be responsible for closing it, or is it legitimate to open it and never close it.

Comment: It isn't just about closing the resource: it also propagates suppressed exceptions. And keeps the variables in a tight scope.

Comment: If you don't close it, you might run out of resources like file handles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for every API involving scarce or external resources (such as file descriptors or streams) will make it clear whose responsibility it is to clean up (in this case, close the stream). This is sometimes referred to as "ownership".

In this case the documentation states that the `loadFont` method does not take ownership of the stream. Therefore it still belongs to you: It is your responsibility to close the stream.

The try-with-resources statement is the best way to do this.